# Will session.invalidate() clears all the session related data?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Please explain about the functionality of session.invalidate().When session.invalidate() is called while logging out from application will it clear all the seesion related data?
If we login to the application again request.getsession(true) will create a new session right?Please clarify!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`HttpServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) says:

public void invalidate()

Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

Throws: IllegalStateException - if this method is called on an already invalidated session

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Also note that you can use the convenience method `request.getSession()` instead (i.e without any parameters) That does the same as `request.getSession(true)`